# Is multi-target debugging broken in WinDbg?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am trying to debug two processes in a single instance of WinDbg.

I wanted to run one of the processes, but `g` does not seem to be related to the selected process (`|0s`, `|1s`). I can run individual threads with the `~6g` syntax, in which case other threads are frozen. However, even if Thread 6 is running now, the WinDbg command prompt is now disabled, so I can't start other threads.

I also noticed that WinDbg can't perform `g` any more when one of the two processes has ended. WinDbg then states that it cannot find something to run:

```
0:000> |0s
0:000> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0113f97c 000a58be ComparativeDebugging!main+0x97 [c:\...\comparativedebugging.cpp @ 13]
[...]
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
0:000> |
.  0    id: 10e0    create  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
#  1    id: 1eec    exited  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
0:000> |1s
[...]
1:004> k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 00cff938 77027dde ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xc
[...]
1:004> |0s
[...]
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
0:000> ~0g
         ^ No runnable debuggees error in '~0g'
```

As you can see, process 0 is still in `main()` and process 1 has terminated. I could not find a way to let process 0 run to its end.

Another issue is that I can't detach from process 1 (which has ended) but I can detach from process 0:

```
1:004> .detach
Detached
1:004> .detach
Detached
1:004> .detach
Detached
1:004> |
   0    id: 10e0    create  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
.  1    id: 1eec    exited  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
1:004> |0s
[...]
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
0:000> .detach
eax=00000000 ebx=770da920 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=77046e9c esp=00cff93c ebp=00cffa14 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xc:
77046e9c c20800          ret     8
Detached
1:004> |
.  1    id: 1eec    exited  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
```

The next thing that des not work is `.restart`. According the documentation

> CDB and WinDbg can restart a target application if the debugger originally created the application. You can use the .restart command even if the target application has already closed.

In my case I have started both applications using WinDbg (one via File/Open Executable, the other via `.create`) and I expected I could restart them individually. However, when I issue the `.restart` command, WinDbg terminates all processes and only restarts the one that was started using File/Open Executable.

```
0:000> .create c:\...\ComparativeDebugging.exe
[...]
Create will proceed with next execution
0:000> g
[...]
0:000> |
.  0    id: 1fa0    create  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
   1    id: 3a20    create  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
0:000> |1s
1:004> .restart
CommandLine: "C:\...\ComparativeDebugging.exe" 5
[....]
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
7707ccbc cc              int     3
0:000> |
.  0    id: 3580    create  name: ComparativeDebugging.exe
```

Am I doing something wrong or is multi-target debugging seriously broken in WinDbg?

I'm using WinDbg 10.0.10586.567 x86 on Windows 10.

Comment: try windbg from 14393 SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Ok, downloaded and installed. I'll try...

Comment: does the newer version work?